# Which is the best option to query postgres node js?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, microservices, database-performance

i want to make scalable micro services for millions of user with node js and postgres i want to know which is the best 
way to query with  db, either by using orm or by  postgres stored function?

Answer (score 1):

The "best" way is kind of a vague question.

If you just want access to Postgres, you can use a package like [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg).

If you want a little more flexibility in your queries, I'd suggest [KnexJS](http://knexjs.org). That's a fun way to write a few queries.

A stored procedure might be "fast" or whatever you're looking for it to be, but if you don't know your domain for the microservice, you'll be spending a lot of time updating that stored procedure and your nodejs package won't matter that much.

Lots of unknowns here, but I'd suggest just using knex (or an ORM if that kind of modeling will help you) until you reach millions of users, and then see if optimizing your microservice with stored functions is the right path forward at that time. You might have a few other concerns by then : )